# How to get IMEI number from Android device on first time install of Application using IONIC 3

Tags: async-await, ionic3, imei

I want to fetch IMEI number of Android device using Ionic 3.
I am using below code to fetch that by following this link.https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/uid/.

```
async getImei() {
 const { hasPermission } = await this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(
   this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
 );

 if (!hasPermission) {
   const result = await this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(
     this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.READ_PHONE_STATE
   );

   if (!result.hasPermission) {
     throw new Error('Permissions required');
   }

   // ok, a user gave us permission, we can get him identifiers after restart app
   return;
 }

  return this.uid.IMEI
}
```

I am calling the above method in constructor like this.

```
this.getImei();
```

Then i just want to print that console.

```
console.log("IMEI Number" + this.uid.IMEI);
```

Here I am facing one problem.For the first time when i am installing application on device, it is asking for permission , but in console am not getting any value.

When i am closing the Application,clearing from backstack, And then when I am opening the Application again that time I am getting value.

Can anyone please help me how to get value on First time installation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are first checking the permission. If the user doesn't have it (which will always be the case when you start it for the first time), you go into the if. Inside you request the permission, but after the user gives you permission, you just do `return;` without any value. So it will return nothing.

The second time you are starting the app, you already have the permission and it skips the if and goes directly to `return this.uid.IMEI`

So you should return the first `return;` to `return this.uid.IMEI`

Comment: I have tried that aswell. But still it is the same @Andreas Gassmann

Comment: Yes , that also i have tried. platform.ready().then(() => {});.But not working @Andreas Gassmann